# Peewee-async - How to do a simple JOIN (or subquery / prefetch)

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I'm stuck on a pretty simple issue with `peewee-async` regarding JOINs, or perhaps I need to use a subquery, or prefetch... I can't figure it out what kind of query I need to do.

I have 2 database tables (parent/child):

```py
class Group(PeeweeModel):
    id = peewee.AutoField()

    name = peewee.TextField()


class Channel(PeeweeModel):
    id = peewee.AutoField()

    name = peewee.TextField()
    group = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Group, backref="channels")
```

I need to fetch 1 group object, and this object has multiple channel objects.

I tried:

```py
q = Group.select(Group, Channel).join(Channel)
```

But my `backref` 'channels' is always a `ModelQuery` instance, not the actual resultset.

#### Full code

```py
import asyncio

import peewee
import peewee_async
from peewee_async import Manager, PooledPostgresqlDatabase

database = PooledPostgresqlDatabase('test', max_connections=4, user='postgres', password='', host='127.0.0.1')
objects = peewee_async.Manager(database)


class PeeweeModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database


class Group(PeeweeModel):
    id = peewee.AutoField()

    name = peewee.TextField()


class Channel(PeeweeModel):
    id = peewee.AutoField()

    name = peewee.TextField()
    group = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Group, backref="channels")


Group.create_table()
Channel.create_table()
database.set_allow_sync(False)


async def handler():
    # create 1 group object
    group = await objects.create(Group, name="TestGroup")

    # create 2 channel objects, assign to group
    await objects.create(Channel, name="TestName1", group=group)
    await objects.create(Channel, name="TestName2", group=group)

    # Query 1 group, and hopefully it will have the channels
    q = Group.select(Group, Channel).join(Channel)

    results = await objects.execute(q)
    for result in results:
        print(result.channels)  # problem: Channels is not a list of channel objects, but a `ModelSelect` instead

    with objects.allow_sync():
        Channel.drop_table(True)
        Group.drop_table(True)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(handler())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get help from an expert™ and the solution is to use `prefetch()`:

```py
async def handler():
    # create 1 group object
    group = await objects.create(Group, name="TestGroup")

    # create 2 channel objects, assign to group
    await objects.create(Channel, name="TestName", group=group)
    await objects.create(Channel, name="TestName", group=group)

    # Query 1 group, and hopefully it will have the channels
    q = Group.select(Group)

    groups = await objects.prefetch(q, Channel.select(Channel))
    for group in groups:
        print(group, group.channels)  # channels is a list of channels.

    with objects.allow_sync():
        Channel.drop_table(True)
        Group.drop_table(True)
```

Peewee will figure out the relationship (backref) by itself.